# Cache only 1 route component dynamically using keep-alive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to set keep alive conditionally to some of my route components and be able to clear the cached routes and set the new cached route.
My code below works but I cannot clear the cached components.

I have meta prop on the routes that I want to cache

```
        {
            name: 'Route1',
            path: '/route1',
            component: lazyLoading('route1', true),
            meta: {
                auth: true,
                cacheRoute: 'Route1',
            },
        },
        {
            name: 'Route2',
            path: '/route2',
            component: lazyLoading('route1', true),
            meta: {
                auth: true,
                cacheRoute: 'Route2',
            },
        },
```

and then i use beforeEach method on my router.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.cacheRoute && store.getters.cachedRouteObject.cached !== 
    to.meta.cacheRoute)
        store.dispatch('cacheRoute', {
            cached: to.meta.cacheRoute,
            uncached: from.meta.cacheRoute,
        }).then(() => {
            next();
        });
    next();
});
```

And use the vuex cachedRouteObject like this:

```
    <keep-alive :include="cachedRouteObject.cached" 
    :exclude="cachedRouteObject.uncached">
        <router-view></main-router-view>
    </keep-alive>
```

The point is that over time when i switch from route to route all the components that have to be cached stay cached so i end up with many cached components. instead of just 1. it seems exclude attribute does not work as i have expected. any ideas on how to always cache just one route component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `keep-alive` the component names, not the route names.

> The match is first checked on the component’s own name option, then
> its local registration name (the key in the parent’s components
> option) if the name option is not available. Anonymous components
> cannot be matched against.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Comment: im passing the names of the components themselves they just match the route name